# How to get a basis for an eigenspace

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I don't see how the book I'm using gets the following eigenvectors.
[image]

I got two vectors for the basis while the book only got one for each eigenvalue.  Can anyone explain how?  I got $x = x_2[0;1;0] + x_3[1;0;1]$, while the book got $x = v_1 = [-1;1;0]$.

Comment: Well, for the eigenvalue $\lambda = 8$, we have the rref of $[A-8I]v_1 = 0$ as $\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)v_1 = 0 \implies v_1 = (-1,1,0)$. Can you do the next two now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the eigenvectors corresponding to an eigenvalue $\lambda$, compute the kernel of the matrix: $A - \lambda I$.

Therefore to find the eigenvectors corresponding to $8$. Look at $$A - 8I = \begin{pmatrix}
-2 & -2 & -1 \\
-2 & -2 & -1 \\
-1 & -1 & -3
\end{pmatrix}_.$$

Row reducing this matrix (this is not echelon form, but is good enough) gives
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 & -3 \\
0 & 0 & 5 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}_.$$

If  $\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $8$, it is in the kernel of the above matrix.

And so from the second row we see that $5x_3 = 0$, i.e. $x_3 = 0$.

And from the first row, $-x_1-x_2 = -x_1-x_2-3x_3 = 0$. So $x_1 = -x_2$.

So $$\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
-x_2\\
x_2\\
0
\end{pmatrix} = x_2 \begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}_.$$

So we see that any eigenvector corresponding to $8$ is a scalar multiple of $\begin{pmatrix}
-1\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}_.$

Computing the eigenvectors corresponding to other eigenvalues works similarly.

Comment: That makes sense, I was forgetting how to go from the ref matrix you have above to v1 (I thought it would result in v1 = [1 1 0]).  Now I get it. Thanks so much.

Comment: For my own edification,say I have a matrix A and two unique lambda values, if I end up with a matrix (A - lambda*I) which when reduced turns out to [1 0.5 -1 0 ; 0 0 0 0 ; 0 0 0 0], can I just pick any values for x1 - x3 which satisfy this matrix, or will the basis for each value of lambda not be orthogonal when I diagonalize this matrix?  For example, for my first lambda I get the aforementioned matrix, and both a basis of v1 = [1 0 1] and v1 = [-1 2 0] satisfy the matrix.  But when I create my P matrix using the basis (from their corresponding v basis matrices) will P be orthogonal?